# x and y Offseting / Bit shifting

Tags: java

I'm really confused with this method, mainly because I'm confused why he bit shifts in some parts.

I have no idea why a map width mask is used or anything here its all so confusing, can someone dissect this all for me?

```
public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 64;
public static final int MAP_WIDTH_MASK = MAP_WIDTH - 1;

public int[] tiles = new int[MAP_WIDTH * MAP_WIDTH];
public int[] colours = new int[MAP_WIDTH * MAP_WIDTH * 4];

public int xOffSet = 0;
public int yOffSet = 0;

public int width;
public int height;

public void render(int[] pixels, int offset, int row) {
    for(int yTile = yOffSet >> 3; yTile <= (yOffSet +height) >> 3; yTile++) {
        int yMin = yTile * 8 - yOffSet;
        int yMax = yMin + 8;
        if(yMin <0) yMin = 0;
        if(yMax > height) yMax = height;

        for(int xTile = xOffSet >> 3; xTile <= (xOffSet + width) >> 3; xTile++) {
            int xMin = xTile * 8 - xOffSet;
            int xMax = xMin + 8;
            if(xMin <0) xMin = 0;
            if(xMax > width) xMax = width;

            int tileIndex = (xTile & (MAP_WIDTH_MASK)) + (yTile & (MAP_WIDTH_MASK)) * MAP_WIDTH;

            for(int y= yMin; y<yMax; y++) {
                int sheetPixel = ((y + yOffSet) & 7) * sheet.width + ((xMin + xOffSet) & 7 );
                int tilePixel = offset + xMin + y * row;
                for(int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
                    int colour = tileIndex * 4 + sheet.pixels[sheetPixel++];
                    pixels[tilePixel++] = colours[colour];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does?

Answer (score 0):

For the `xOffset >> 3` sorts of things, it appears he's just trying to divide by 8 (and doesn't know how to make readable code). As for why he's masking all of the bits except the last 3, I couldn't say without knowing more about the code.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably help:

- `y >> 3` is equivalent to `y / 8` rounded down; it moves everything over to erase the last three bits.
- `y * 8` is the equivalent to `y << 3`. Beats me why he didn't stay consistent between the two of them.
- `y & 7` is the equivalent to `y % 8`; it keeps only the last three bits.

You didn't mention `sheet` in your description, but it looks like you're working with "tiles" of 8 pixels by 8 pixels on a map of 64 pixels by 64 pixels. One thing that may help is a refactoring tool--see if you can extract some methods that make sense.